# How to update quote in magento2

Tags: magento2, quote, quoteitem

I want to update quote by quote id I have quote id . I have created the custom function on that function every time it's creating new quote row . I want to check if quote exists then update only else create.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use CartRepository: `\Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface`.

Inject it via Constructor of your class

```
protected $quoteRepository;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository,
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
    ....
}
```

and use in required method as:

```
$quote = $this->quoteRepository->get($quoteId);
$quote->setCustomerId($customerId); // Whatever you want to update
$this->quoteRepository->save($quote)
```

Refer - [Magento 2: Understanding Object Repositories](http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_understanding_object_repositories)

Comment: Its overriding the data i want to update this will override the data for ex. that quote is having items_qty = 1 , if i will update then it should add the qty not override

Comment: @magento12345 why don't you read the current qty first, then sum it with new qty, and override it?